# Can we Control the logging level of a particular library using logback.xml?

Tags: spring-boot, logging

I am trying to change to log level of the library for example

com .spotify.docker.client

I have added

`<logger name="com .spotify.docker.client " level="ERROR"/>`

in my logback.xml
But still, the logs from that library are getting printed in the info level.

Comment: Hi! Is there actually a space between `com` and `.spotify` in your file?

Comment: I might have added that mistake here by mistake but never mind I figured out why it was not working